# Samsung TV - mode not supported

Tags: resolution, samsung

I am trying to install Ubuntu on an old Aopen XC cube. It works fine on a normal PC screen, but when I connect it to the Samsung flat-screen TV I am going to use it on, I get the message `Mode not supported`.

If I first log in connected to the PC screen and then change to the Samsung it works. But every time I boot up connected to the TV, I get the mode not supported message. And if I then change back to the PC screen I only get the option to choose between a few crappy resolutions and none of the are supported by the Samsung.

When I Googled it, it seemed that some have had the same problem with PS3 on Samsung flat-screens.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Ok,

I got it working on the TV by cyceling through the resolutions by using the Alt Ctrl +/- key-command.

But there only a few low resolutions to choose from. And the only ones that work are 576 x 720 and 576 x 768

When i connected it to the tv after booting up on a pc monitor i had it working on 1280 x 1024.

Comment: So this is an answer, but not a _satisfactory_ one? Would you mind adding a link to your question to a page at http://paste.ubuntu.com containing the contents of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`? Please do this from both when you startup with your TV connected, and from when you start-up with your monitor. You can get file content by navigating to the file starting from The Folder icon in the launcher and examine its contents by double clicking when you have reached it. I suspect something is wrong with the horizontal or vertical frequencies reported by the TV to Ubuntu.